# mayavi remotely running on Jupyter notebook

Tags: mayavi.mlab

I trying to run the following code in Jupyter Notebook. But it didn't work and throw out that the server is done.

I could import mayavi, but I could not 'from mayavi import malb'

%gui qt

from mayavi import mlab

import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.mgrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]

s = np.sin(x*y*z)/(x*y*z)

mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(x,y,z,s))

mlab.savefig('test')

The sever just shut down.